# Pandas-way to groupby like itertools.groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I want

```
>> x = np.arange(0,4*np.pi,0.1)
>> y = np.sin(x)
>> df = pd.DataFrame(index=x, data=y)

>> map(lambda (k, v): (k, list(v)), groupby(np.sin(x), lambda x: x>=0))
[(True,
  [0.0, ..., 0.041580662433290491]),
 (False,
  [-0.058374143427580086, ..., -0.083089402817496397]),
 (True,
  [0.016813900484350601, ..., 0.024775425453357765]),
 (False,
  [-0.075151120461809301, ..., -0.066321897351200684])
]
```

But in a more "pandas-way" using `df`.

`pd.groupby(.)` (as far as I know) gives me just 2 groups instead of 4.

Comment: So why don't you rewrite this using `pandas.DataFrame.groupby`? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Comment: Yes but I will only get 2 bins (true, false) with pandas.groupby, which I want to avoid..

Answer (score 1):

You could use `diff` followed by `cumsum` to give each group of Trues and Falses its own number:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
x = np.arange(0,4*np.pi,0.1)
y = np.sin(x)
df = pd.DataFrame(y, index=x)

mask = np.sin(df[0])>=0
groupnum = mask.diff().fillna(method='bfill').fillna(0).cumsum()
print([(key, grp.head()) for key, grp in df.groupby(groupnum)])
```

yields

```
[(0,             0
0.0  0.000000
0.1  0.099833
0.2  0.198669
0.3  0.295520
0.4  0.389418), (1,             0
3.2 -0.058374
3.3 -0.157746
3.4 -0.255541
3.5 -0.350783
3.6 -0.442520), (2,             0
6.3  0.016814
6.4  0.116549
6.5  0.215120
6.6  0.311541
6.7  0.404850), (3,             0
9.5 -0.075151
9.6 -0.174327
9.7 -0.271761
9.8 -0.366479
9.9 -0.457536)]
```

Comment: This seems to give a difference for those dataframes that are of length one, which sometimes happens in my pipeline. Calling `diff`` on those results in an empty df, which results in no groups.

Comment: To handle dataframes of length one, add `.fillna(0)` before calling `cumsum`. (See edit above.)